# Visual C++ won't create the dll file and stops at the *.lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I inherited a dll project (Visual C++ 2002) and I'm having a lot of trouble to compile it. Even though the *.def file is in the current dir, VC will only create a lib file, instead of the dll.

Anybody knows what might be going on?

Comment: Sounds like a static library project rather than a DLL project. Are you sure it's a DLL project?

Comment: Yes.  It was actually a problem with the output dir that was pointing to a network drive.  Never mind. O:-)

Comment: if you find the solution yourself, please answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was actually a problem with the output dir that was pointing to a network drive. The dll was created, but placed in an odd folder.